# Microsoft Azure Table Storage - Create New Table

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm new to Azure Table Storage, and after creating an accound, I'm completely unable to figure out how to create a table. I have downloaded the Storage Explorer, but I only get error messages trying to connect to the account.

So, a very simple question, how do I crate a table?

Comment: `but I only get error messages trying to connect to the account` - How are you connecting to this storage account? Have you provided proper account name/key?

Comment: There is plenty of documentation around Azure Table Storage with examples for creating tables if they don't exist, via several different programming languages. Please edit your question to show your code. Also - please stick with objectivity - no need to throw shade at a vendor when you can't figure something out; and your color commentary has nothing to do with the issue. I edited your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the newest Storage Explorer support three ways to connect to your azure storage account.

**I suggest you could try to connect to the azure storage account by using your azure account username and password.**

1.Click the icon as the image shows:

[image]

2.Sign in the azure account as below image shows:

[image]

3.Use your username and password login in.

[image]

4.After login success, you could locate your storage account's tag and right click the table selection to create a new table:

[image]

**Besides, you could also use account key and account name to connect to your azure storage account in Storage Explorer.**

I suggest you could refer to below steps:

1.Select use a storage account name and key click next:

[image]

2.Find your storage account name and key in the portal and add them in the storage explorer.

[image]

3.At last you could find your storage account in the local and attached tag as below.

Right click the tables, you could create new table.

[image]

**If you want to know how to create table by codes, I suggest you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables).**

Note: This is C# version, if you want to change the language version, you could refer to below image:

[image]